# WCF restful service not found

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

Hi all I'm trying to build WCF rest (Ajax enabled) I watch some tutorial in the YouTube as well as  I read some questions about this topic in Stackoverflow.

I found some missing element in my web.config I thought the problem was completely fixed, but unfortunately I'm facing new problem now that is service not found.

this is web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AjaxAndWCF.GetEmployeeAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="AjaxAndWCF.GetEmployee" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="../GetEmployee.svc" behaviorConfiguration="AjaxAndWCF.GetEmployeeAspNetAjaxBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" contract="AjaxAndWCF.IGetEmployee" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:51520/GetEmployee.svc/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

this is the service

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class GetEmployee : IGetEmployee
{
    public Employee byId(int id)
    {

        Employee emp = new Employee();

        String strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WCFTOAJAXT1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ProGetEmployeeById", con);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();

            parameter.ParameterName = "@Id";
            parameter.Value = id;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                emp.Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]);
                emp.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                emp.Nationality = rdr["Nationality"].ToString();
                emp.Email = rdr["Email"].ToString();
            }

        }

        return emp;/*
        return new Employee()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "test",
            Nationality = "test",
            Email ="test@test.com"
        };*/

    }
}
```

this is the service contract

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/byId?id=id",
        Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Employee byId(int id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Address in the endpoint is BASED off of the base address.  Since you don't seem to have any other endpoints, you may as well hang your RESTFUL webservice off of the root address...blank out the address in your endpoint like below and let me know if this fixes it.

```
<service name="AjaxAndWCF.GetEmployee" 
         behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address=""
         behaviorConfiguration="AjaxAndWCF.GetEmployeeAspNetAjaxBehavior"
         binding="webHttpBinding" 
         contract="AjaxAndWCF.IGetEmployee" />
    <host>
       <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:51520/GetEmployee.svc/"/>
       </baseAddresses>
    </host>
</service>
```

And then your url will be ***http://localhost:51520/GetEmployee.svc/byid?id=5***

I usually format my urls like "/byid/{id}" so I haven't tried to see if this method works, but I'm assuming you got that code from somewhere.

Comment: Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.

Comment: What is saying that?  Test client?  Add service reference?  Can you type the url and get to it?

Comment: RESTful services don't have metadata.  You don't add a service reference for it like you do a SOAP service.

Comment: That's what I was getting at Tim...a more direct approach like you did was better.  :)  @user3141505  'HttpClient' or 'WebClient' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx